# alfresco activiti new workflow add

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, jbpm, activiti

I have alfresco community 4.0.e.

I deployed new workflow and used task listener for one of it's tasks;

```
<activiti:taskListener event="create" class="java.JavaBpmnTest"></activiti:taskListener>
```

and here is my java class

```
package java;

import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;

public class JavaBpmnTest implements JavaDelegate{

@Override
public void execute(DelegateExecution arg0) throws Exception {
    /* my code */
}

/**
 * @param args
 */

}
```

My question is where to put this java file so my workflow can work with it?
How to deploy this java file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create jar file and put it under alfresco/WEB-INF/lib.

All your imports will be already loaded in class path when alfresco is running.